# Enhance a function and turn it off when window size is below 770px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On my project page there are two grid, one for images and one for a box that contains information about the project, the information box is positioned fixed so it scroll with the page - and with the JavaScript below I managed to get it stop scrolling when it reach the footer. Take a look here: http://meeped.co.uk:93/portfolio/ambition-world.html[1](http://meeped.co.uk:93/portfolio/ambition-world.html)

The problem I am having is, on very small screens like iphone, I want to disable the scrolling, and give each grid (images grid, information box) a 100%. But I can't seems to know how I can stop the function from firing and turn it back on when the screen size is over 770. I have almost done it, but since on the function it adds margins to it, the margins will stay when it's disabled on small screens which generates a big empty space that I can't get rid off. any ideas?

```
//StickyBox
$(function () {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function () {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };
    var $StickyBox = $('.detailsBox');
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function () {
        var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop < 50) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });

        } else if (visibleFoot > gap - 100) {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });

        } else {
            $StickyBox.css({
                top: 80,
                bottom: "auto"

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Where in your function do you check for the screensize? I don't see anything with 770?

Comment: I tried to warp it in this: `$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(this).width() > 770 ) {
       
    }
});` but it didn't work

Comment: And that didn't work?

Comment: no mate, i have no idea what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
if($window.width() <= 770) { 
    // reset your sticky box's margins
    $StickyBox.css({
      top: 'auto',
      bottom: 'auto'
    });
    return;
}
```

after your declared vars in your event listener, like:

```
$window.bind("scroll resize", function () {
    var gap = $window.height() - $StickyBox.height() - 10;
    var visibleFoot = 255 - $window.scrollBottom();
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

    if($window.width() <= 770) { 
        // reset your sticky box's margins
        $StickyBox.css({
          top: 'auto',
          bottom: 'auto'
        });
        return;
    }

    if (scrollTop < 50) {
        $StickyBox.css({
            top: (130 - scrollTop) + "px",
            bottom: "auto"
        });

    } else if (visibleFoot > gap - 100) {
        $StickyBox.css({
            top: "auto",
            bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
        });

    } else {
        $StickyBox.css({
            top: 80,
            bottom: "auto"
        });
    }
```

Add this right after all your vars are declared in your `$window.bind("scroll resize"` callback.

Comment: As in disabled that your code is acting how you wanted it to? Or it broke? Your code looks like what I edited the above to look like?

Comment: It has been disabled from all screen sizes no matter, i only want it to be disabled when it's under 770 wide

Comment: This did Work! however, all the margins that are added when it is undisabled are still there, is there anyway we can reset it? or get rid of them?

Comment: sure just put the margin reset code before the return statement; see above.

Comment: Sorry mate, what do you mean, please bear with me i am new to this - took me few weeks to finally do this script

Comment: Well by 'margins' I'm assuming you mean the 'top' and 'bottom' properties. Just set them up however it is you want them to be. $StickyBox.css({ top: 'whatever your reset is', bottom: 'whatever your reset is' });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36865/discussion-between-leo-and-devin)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$window.bind("scroll resize", function () {
   if($(this).width() < 770) {
       return;
   }

   // rest of your code...
```

Comment: it has disabled all the other JavaScript that are on the same page as well as the function it self even above 770

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(window).width() > 770) {
      // if it is more than 770
   } else {
      // if it is less or equal
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function onlyIfWidthGreaterThan(width, fn) {
    if ($(window).width() > width) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

usage like:

```
onlyIfWidthGreaterThan(770, function() {
    // do your stuff

});
```